# Run a legacy system in Yii for maintaining, but the routes don't work

Tags: php, yii, routes

I'm trying to put a legacy system in Yii 1.1 to work, but somethings are not running well. I never used Yii before and the documentation is very confused.

Now i already make the homepage to work, but when i click in a link, the routes are ignored, so apache returns a 404 error. Learning in documentation, setup a new installation works, i run the yiic command to run a webapp and work exactly as suggested, but the system that's running online don't work in localhost.

Documentation don't tell nothing about maintain a existing Yii app, but i'm thinking that i need to run some yiic command, because in repository has only the logic, i downloaded the framework from Yii website.

Someone already installed a Yii legacy code to give a way to make it work? What makes me intrigued is that i setup my database and the homepage access this to bring information, but the routes simply don't work

Comment: what type of link you have? have you created .htaccess file? what url pattern you are using?

Comment: Semantics, like /your-account, and i'm using .htaccess from the running server

Comment: can you show some example also check url pattern in main.php file under config folder, for more detail have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: I can't show the code :( But my idea that i need to run some kind of yiic command to put this to work is not needed? This is only for new apps?